# No working example available to demonstrate CucumberJS integration with TestCafe showing RestAPI test scenario, can somebody suggest an approach?

Tags: rest, testing, testcafe, cucumberjs, web-api-testing

I have been exploring the projects on GitHub which demonstrates the capabilities of integrating TestCafe with CucumberJS, however, I am not able to find any reference to test the RestAPI through this integration and I need it as per my project requirements.

Can I request someone to post a working example, currently I am exploring the following repo: https://github.com/rquellh/testcafe-cucumber

I have already tried to explore the projects available on GitHub:

https://github.com/search?p=3&q=testcafe+cucumber&type=Repositories

I am expecting the Cucumber BDD driven workflow based on TestCafe:

https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options here.
 
If you want to test RestAPI itself by sending requests from a test scenario and checking a response, you don't need TestCafe for this. According to [this issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2397) TestCafe still cannot make HTTP requests. Furthermore, Request Handlers cannot handle requests you make from your test code using external tools. They work only for requests that a testing page makes.
 
If a script on your testing page makes RestAPI requests and you want to know what is in response, you can just add a request logger like this:

```js
let requestLogger = null;
 
Given('I use example.com REST API', async function () {
  requestLogger = RequestLogger(/https:\/\/api\.example\.com/, {
    logResponseHeaders: true,
    logResponseBody: true
  });

  await testController.addRequestHooks(requestLogger);
});
```

And then you can obtain data from `requestLogger` as described in the [Test API documentation](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/#logging-http-requests).

Comment: Thanks @Alexey Lindberg, this question should rather be handled by devexpress to introduce api test capabilities to the tool. Accepting the work around that you have proposed. I am using axios and fetch as of now to test the api.

Comment: can you please look into the code and help:  '`const apiBaseUrl = 'https://api.test.samplewebsite.com.au/';
    const apiLogger = RequestLogger(apiBaseUrl, {
        logResponseHeaders: true,
        logResponseBody: true
      });
    
    await testController.addRequestHooks(apiLogger);
    await testController.navigateTo('https://baseurl.sitecore-scaled-test-cm.azurewebsites.net/').expect(apiLogger.contains(r => r.response.statusCode === 200)).ok();`' I am not able to figure out why I am  getting the error: 'errMsg: 'AssertionError: expected false to be truthy' }'

Comment: According to the [Select Requests to be Handled by the Hook](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/select-requests-to-be-handled-by-the-hook.html#filter-by-url) topic, you are filtering requests by an exact url: 'https://api.test.samplewebsite.com.au/'. If it is only a part of the request url, try to use the Regular Expression instead. For example: `const urlRegExp = new RegExp('https://api.test.samplewebsite.com.au'); const apiLogger = RequestLogger(urlRegExp, { logResponseHeaders: true, logResponseBody: true });`.